# Steam error: “You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and steam may not run: libXtst.so.6 libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0”

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, dpkg, sudo, steam

I’m trying to install steam on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

It downloaded everything correctly from what I can tell, but crashes upon launching. It says:

“You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and steam may not run:
libXtst.so.6
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0”

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0` and `sudo apt install libxtst6` - that _should_ create the .so's you're missing but probably won't work (or apt would have done it automatically), however it'll give you some enlightening error messages.

Comment: Both say they are already the newest version, which makes me think it's something wrong with steam.

Comment: ah, try `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386` - note the `:i386` on the end which specifies the 32 bit version of the library. You may have to run `dpkg --add-architecture i386` before that one.

Comment: Well that solved the 2nd error, but the libXtst.so.6 is still not being found.

Comment: same deal: `sudo apt install libxtst6:i386`

Comment: Well steam really doesn't like me. both of those errors are gone, but now it can't load module 'vgui2_s.so'. I assume this is on steams end, their support page doesn't explain much, but if you know anything it would be appreciated.

Comment: This one probably means that library is missing dependencies. `cd ~/.steam/bin` and then run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd vgui2_s.so` - it should print a list of the dependencies of that so; try installing any that are listed as "not found". How exactly did you install Steam here? It shouldn't be anything like this much work - normally dependencies like this are just automatically reconciled during the install.

Comment: Alright I found the missing dependencies, and to avoid making this thread to long, I'm going to see if I can get it from here. also I just downloaded steam using the install command. I didn't do any weird stuff to complicate it.

Comment: good luck! Actually I forgot steam is a bit of an odd one; rather than apt doing the install, the package that apt installs is just a bootstrap thingy that itself downloads and installs steam proper the first time you try to run the program, so I guess something went awry there. Hope you get it working anyway.

Answer (score 4):

These are the best commands I've found to work for me. Enter them in this exact order:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386 libc6-i386
wget https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/client/installer/steam.deb
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
sudo apt -f install
steam --disable-framerate-limit
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the 32 bit version of those two .so's by installing these packages:

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt install libxtst6:i386
```

The ":i386" suffix specifies the 32 bit version of the package. Note that this step may be a prerequisite (it doesn't seem to be for me, but people often report that it is).

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Comment: Solved this issue in my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem installing Ubuntu 22.04 (KDE Neon based on Jammy) and have been able to fix it by downgrading some lib versions:
https://www.ambience.sk/fix-steam-on-ubuntu-22-04-you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-and-steam-may-not-run-libgl-so-1/

The steps include adding i386 architecture as mentioned in other answers, and then:

> apt-cache showpkg libxml2
>
> You should see multiple version of libxml2 available. As libxml2:i386 is only available as 2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 and libxml2:amd64 is in higher version such as 2.9.14+dfsg-0+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, you won’t be able to install i386 version.
>
> The solution is to downgrade amd64 version via (repeat for other lib conflicts):
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libxml2=2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 libxml2-dev=2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1
> ```
>
> Then install i386 versions of libraries you are missing for Steam (add any further ones you need):
>
> ```
> sudo apt install libxml2:i386 libgl1:i386
> ```

Comment: Rather than just including the link, it would be best to include the exact libs that needed to be downgraded, ideally with the code required for doing so. Please [edit] your answer to include the essential parts of the linked page with the link for reference only. Thanks!