# Steam doesn't launch on Ubuntu 20.04 ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, games, steam

I installed steam on Ubuntu 20.04 and when I want to run it I get this message in the terminal.

Can some one help me please?

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.


ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgcc_s.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libxcb.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/SLIB/libgpg-error.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/^C
```

Comment: How did you install Steam?  It is available in the standard repos (multiverse) as steam-installer.  What you used is probably not for ubuntu, since /usr/SLIB does not exist, the proper path would be soemthing like /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1

Comment: Hi, i wanted to install this script but instead of $ i type S, do you know how can i delete it? I m new on Ubuntu system.                                                                                    #!/bin/bash

{LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libgpg-error.so' /usr/bin/steam}

Comment: Here it is link of that you-tube video                                                                                                https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdM1S39mjgY

Comment: That link is pretty old.  It's much easier these days. See https://linuxhint.com/install-steamos-on-ubuntu/  and for the 32 bit libraries https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261312/steam-error-you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-and-steam-may-not  Run the gedit editor to change text files gedit yourscript.sh

Comment: Okay, but do you know how i can delete that script because it is causing problems now?

Comment: Here's a beginner's intro to Ubuntu:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4WyNjt_hbQ   Run Files from the launch bar and right click and select "move to trash" to delete things, but then if something else tries to run that scipt, it will fail, so reverse everything you did from your first video, then follow the current steam install link instructions.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help.